# Android Notifications disappear after some time

Tags: android, notifications

Android notifications disappear after some time, without touching it to cancel. What could cause this kind of problem? The notification is started in a Service.
Is that possible that the low memory causes this kind of problem?

Comment: Is there anyway that an other service call NotificationManager.Cancel() or .cancelAll() for that notification ?
EDIT : make sure .setAutoCancel(true); is not set in your notification builder

Comment: This is a good point, actually I've tried to remove cancelAll from another modules and used unique ids for notifications, but you may be right that I still have the same issue in a different place.

Comment: @SimonPA Concerning setAutoCancel is true, but I think it has a different purpose and you need to touch it to cancel. That's what written in the documentation.

Comment: true, setAutoCancel is user interaction based, I missed that. If fix it and figure it was not cancelAll(), please let me know, it might help me one day.

Comment: @SimonPA Could you please put your hint as an answer. Because that was the problem in my case.

Comment: Yes of course. Glad to see it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that there is no any other service or project module, which does the following call `NotificationManager.cancelAll()` to cancel all the notifications. It is always better to keep the notifications controller over Unique ID and cancel only the notifications which are related to that part, by this the code won't touch the notifications posted by other project parts.

[NotificationManager documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html)